# Adjusting x limits xlim() in ggplot2 geom_density() to mimic ggvis layer_densities() behavior

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

Is there a way to make ggplot2's `geom_density()` function mimic the behavior of ggvis's `layer_densities()`?  That is, make it so `p1` looks like `p3` (see below) without the call to `xlim()`?  Specifically, I prefer the view that smooths the tails of the density curve.

```
library(ggvis)
library(ggplot2)

faithful %>% 
  ggvis(~waiting) %>% 
  layer_densities(fill := "green") -> p1

ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
  geom_density(fill = "green", alpha = 0.2) -> p2

ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
  geom_density(fill = "green", alpha = 0.2) +
  xlim(c(30, 110)) -> p3

p1
p2
p3
```

ggvis Output:
[image: p1]

ggplot2 "default":
[image: p2]

ggplot2 "desired":
[image: p3]

Note: One can make ggvis mimic ggplot2 via the following (using `trim=TRUE`), but I would like to go the other direction...

```
faithful %>% 
  compute_density(~waiting, trim=TRUE) %>% 
  ggvis(~pred_, ~resp_) %>% 
  layer_lines()
```

Comment: Why avoiding the xlim argument? Is your concern that the solution will not be general enough?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik correct - I'm looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about calling `xlim`, but with limits that are defined programmatically?

```
l <- density(faithful$waiting)
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
  geom_density(fill = "green", alpha = 0.2) +
  xlim(range(l$x))
```

[image]

The downside is double density estimation though, so keep that in mind.